# Set zoom level in MapTiler plugin for QGIS

Tags: qgis, zoom, maptiler

I use the MapTiler plugin to create the map. And I want to show the road network as well.
It would be great to have the ability to display roads regardless of zoom level.
[image]
[image]
The pictures show what zoom level 6 and 7 looks like. I would like to achieve the result that at level 6 what is shown at level 7 was displayed.
Is this possible using the MapTiler plugin?